# Reassigning ByteArrayOutputStream behaviour

Tags: java

I'm facing a memory error while using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write a file. The code is the following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream data = getNewData();

while (data.size() > 0) {
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("data.txt", true)) {
        data.writeTo(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    data = getNewData();
}
```

I'm suspecting that reassigning the variable `data` does not clear the old value somehow, but I do not know how to prove that since theoretically the Garbage Collector should remove the older value. I guess I'm missing something...

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: I don't know since `getNewData` is retrieving new data  from an external service every time it's called

Comment: You re-assign `data` after the loop. So unless `getNewData` returns the same object each time it is called, the reason is probably that the input is too large given the JVM heap settings used when the program is run.

Comment: but `getNewData` returns a dataset of the exact same size and it gives memory error after some iterations

Comment: It might be useful to post `::getNewData` too

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector will clean up the old `ByteArrayOutputStream` once `data` has been reassigned. But this reassignment takes place only when `getNewData()` returns. While `getNewData()` is running you will have the old `ByteArrayOutputStream` (referenced by `data`) and a new `ByteArrayOutputStream` (presumably created within `getNewData()`) in memory.

You can de-reference the old `ByteArrayOutputStream` early:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream data = getNewData();

while (data.size() > 0) {
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("data.txt", true)) {
        data.writeTo(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    data = null;    
    data = getNewData();
}
```

Comment: this does not seem to be working... it still runs out of memory

Comment: Instead of *data = null;* try `data.reset();`

Comment: Then, there is no way around redesigning your software, to let `getNewData()` write into a caller specified `OutputStream` directly, instead of keeping the entire contents in the heap memory. Mind that writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` without a pre-calculated capacity can require up to three times the required memory.

Comment: @g00se `ByteArrayOutputStream.reset()` only sets the position (`count`) to 0, it does not clear the array it holds.

Comment: Mark you're right, I thought at first the API docs were suggesting something else

Comment: That assignment to `null` is useless if you assign a new value immediately afterwards. With and without the `null` assignment, the old object that `data` refers to becomes eligible for GC once a different value is assigned to it.

Comment: lol, just throw a _= null_ on it, that fixes it.

Comment: Using `ByteArrayOutputStream.reset()` could actually work, but it requires refactoring `getNewData` to reuse the same `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance. After writing the data you reset it, so the next call to `getNewData` could fill the same instance from the start again. But then you might as well refactor `getNewData` to not return anything but instead take an `OutputStream` argument and let the caller determine what type. It could be a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to get similar behaviour, or directly the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @RobSpoor the point is exactly _if you assign a new value immediately afterwards_. From a comment of the OP: _`getNewData` is retrieving new data from an external service_. This implies that `getNewData()` doesn't return immediately but does complex work (and allocates memory). Setting `data` to null allows the garbage collector to do its work if it runs during the execution of `getNewData()`

Comment: @Holger I really don't understand your comment

Comment: @thmasker to fill the `ByteArrayOutputStream` returned by your `getNewData()` method, there must be code writing into it. Rewrite your software so that the caller can pass an `OutputStream` to that code. Then, pass the `FileOutputStream` to that code, maybe wrapped in a `BufferedOutputStream` if the code makes lots of small writes, so it will write to the file directly.

Comment: @ThomasKläger in fact, the complexity of the `getNewData()` method doesn’t matter. By the time, the `getNewData()` returns but the assignment has not happened yet, both, the old and the new `ByteArrayOutputStream` exist in memory. Unless the JVM’s optimizer has transformed the code to not hold the old reference at this point, but we can not rely on the optimizer in such a scenario. Assigning `null` before the invocation like in your answer is a pragmatic solution. If that’s not helping the OP, even one `ByteArrayOutputStream` consumes too much memory and the fundamental redesign is unavoidable

Comment: @ThomasKläger you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm facing a memory error while using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write a file. ..."*

Try utilizing a *byte array*.

Here is an example.

```java
ByteArrayInputStream is = getNewData();
try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("data.txt", true)) {
    int n;
    byte[] b = new byte[1000];
    while ((n = is.read(b)) != -1) os.write(b, 0, n);
}
```

> *"... I'm suspecting that reassigning the variable `data` does not clear the old value somehow, but I do not know how to prove that since theoretically the Garbage Collector should remove the older value. ..."*

Variable assignment will discard any previous value, as per the *Java* syntax.

Comment: Switching to `ByteArrayInputStream` is probably going to make things _worse_. `getNewData()` probably initializes a new `ByteArrayOutputStream`, writes to it and returns it. If it's going to return a `ByteArrayInputStream` instead, the `ByteArrayOutputStream` must be converted. As far as I know, that can only be done by calling `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` which will make a copy of the data. Given that memory is already a problem I would definitely skip this copy.

Comment: I wonder what the solution could be then.

Comment: The signature of `getNewData` gets changed: `long getNewData(OutputStream outputStream)`. Internally, instead of writing to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` that's returned, data is written to the `OutputStream` argument. The return value (could also be an `int`) is the amount of data that is written. The loop would become `long size; do { try (...) { size = getNewData(os); } } while (size > 0);`. The loop stops being processed once `getNewData` returns 0.